convert from TimeInterval to String with func and parameter on output
I can't convert from TimeInterval to String with func and parameter on output.
It gives me this error message:
Cannot convert value of type 'TimeInterval' (aka 'Double') to expected argument type 'Date'
import Foundation

extension Date {

func timeIntervalToString(date: TimeInterval) -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        return dateString
    }

}


Does the TimeInterval represent the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 or something? Otherwise this doesn't make sense.

DateFormatter.string(from:) receives a Date as an input parameter not a TimeInterval.
Your TimeInterval needs to be in a form like 1716889787. It represents the number of seconds since 01/01/1970.
I believe it should be:
func timeIntervalToString(date: TimeInterval) -> String {
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: date) //<- here
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    return dateString
}


Thanks sonle, but what is the difference between timestamp and timeinterval?

They're different names for the same concept.
